# Avoid mimeType validation when no file is uploaded in cakephp 4

Tags: php, file, validation, cakephp-4.x

Here is the validation for my input file "image" :

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
{
    $validator = parent::validationDefault($validator);

    $validator
        ->allowEmptyFile('image')
        ->add('image', 'uploadError', [
            'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                foreach ($value as $v) {
                    return Validation::uploadError($v, true);
                }
            },
            'last' => true,
            'message' => 'Upload error'
        ])
        ->add('image', 'mimeType', [
            'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                foreach ($value as $v) {
                    return Validation::mimeType($v, [
                        'image/png',
                        'image/gif',
                        'image/pjpeg',
                        'image/jpeg'
                    ]);
                }
            },
            'message' => 'Bad mime type.',
        ]);

}
```

It works well when a file is submitted, but when no file is uploaded the mimeType validation error is triggered.

So I've modified mimeType rule to check if a file is uploaded before checking mimeType like that :

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
{
    $validator = parent::validationDefault($validator);

    $validator
        ->allowEmptyFile('image')
        ->add('image', 'uploadError', [
            'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                foreach ($value as $v) {
                    return Validation::uploadError($v, true);
                }
            },
            'last' => true,
            'message' => 'Upload error'
        ])
        ->add('image', 'mimeType', [
            'rule' => function ($value, $context) {

                // Added to avoid mimeType validation when no file is uploaded
                if ($value[0]->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
                    return true;
                }

                foreach ($value as $v) {
                    return Validation::mimeType($v, [
                        'image/png',
                        'image/gif',
                        'image/pjpeg',
                        'image/jpeg'
                    ]);
                }
            },
            'message' => 'Bad mime type.',
        ]);

}
```

It works but it doesn't seem so clean to me to add
`if ($value[0]->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {return true;}`
on every single rule that could be added after mime type check (for example I will add file size check, image width check, etc.)

Is there a better way to add validation rules on file only if a file is submitted ?

Comment: Why is the value an array? That should not be the case for a single upload. And if you have a multi-upload field, then the validation would be wrong.

Comment: The value is an array because I've set the input like that : `echo $this->Form->control('image', ['type' => 'file', 'name' => 'image[]']);`. I'm creating a plugin for file management with an attachment behavior that links files using hasMany association. Instead of managing hasOne and hasMany associations depending on multi-upload files, I thought my code would be clearer if I'd manage only hasMany association even for a single upload file.

Comment: @ndm Indeed, I don't need to add `if ($value[0]->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {return true;}` when $value is not an array. But what about multi-upload input file ? How to validate ?

Comment: That's not what I was trying to suggest, in fact, I didn't mean to suggest anything at this point, I was just wondering about your setup, as possible solutions for your problem might depend on it, and because the validation looks wrong as it only checks the first entry in the array, which could mean that for a multiple file input non-validated files could slip through.

Comment: @ndm In case of multi-upload input the value is an array. Anyway `$value` has always one entry at least : if no file is uploaded `$value` has one entry `[0]` with error on `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`, if there's one or many file(s) uploaded the first entry (file) can't have error on `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`. But it seems ugly to me to check `if ($value[0]->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {return true;}` in each validation rule that I add on the field.

Comment: While that is true for a `<input type="file" name="name[]" multiple />` element, you should not rely on your frontend sending you the data in that specific way, not even when using the form protector (I'm not even sure if it even supports multi file fields), your validation should always assume possible rogue input data! That being said, your loops only validate the first element/file in the array, that's what I was alluding to being a problem. However, we're getting a little bit offtopic.

Comment: So one possibly last question before I suggest a solution, you are currently storing all uploads in a single table, and your behavior attaches a `hasMany` association, even for models that only accept a single file?

Comment: @ndm That's right. (Anyway for now. Maybe I'll add `hasOne` later)

Comment: @ndm If you have any suggestion, it would be welcome :)

Comment: Sorry, I had some work to do and totally forgot about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing how your upload functionality is currently structured, that is all uploads are stored in the same table, and a behavior handles them via a `hasMany` association, including for models that only accept a single file, and the frontend using multi-file inputs, one possible solution would be to simply remove the field in case of an empty file upload.

You can change data via the `Model.beforeMarshal` event/callback, it will run when creating/patching entities, before validation is applied, for example:

```php
public function beforeMarshal(
    \Cake\Event\EventInterface $event,
    \ArrayAccess $data,
    \ArrayObject $options
): void {
    if (
        isset($data['image'][0]) &&
        $data['image'][0] instanceof \Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface &&
        $data['image'][0]->getError() === \UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
    ) {
        unset($data['image']);
    }
}
```

This would remove the `image` field in case it is an array, and the first element is an empty uploaded file object. This is what you'd receive for a multi-file input where no file has been selected, as well as for your single-file input that uses an array for the name.

Your validation rules would then simply not run when the field isn't present anymore, and when they *do* run, they would not have to allow that situation, but instead could strictly require valid uploaded file objects.

So, for example for a model that should only accept a single upload, you could do something like this to ensure the value is an array that holds exactly one element with an uploaded file object:

```php
$validator
    ->add('image', 'exactlyOneUploadedFile', [
        'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
            if (
                is_array($value) &&
                count($value) === 1 &&
                $value[0] instanceof \Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface
            ) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        },
        // ...
    ])
    // ...
```

Similarly, for a model that should accept multiple uploads, you could do something like this to ensure the value is an array that holds one or more elements of only uploaded file objects:

```php
$validator
    ->add('image', 'onlyUploadedFiles', [
        'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
            if (
                !is_array($value) ||
                count($value) < 1
            ) {
                return false;
            }

            foreach ($value as $upload) {
                if (!($upload instanceof \Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        },
        // ...
    ])
    // ...
```

It is important that you really make these checks strict! The validation rules that you've posted would for example only check the first entry in the array, but do not check whether more element exist, which could possibly result in a situation where more than one upload is being sent, and the additional uploads slip through unvalidated!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Modifying Request Data Before Building Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities)**

Comment: Thank you very much ndm for taking the time to reply, I'll try your solution.

Comment: Indeed I get the fact that my validation was wrong because I didn't check the mime type of the second file uploaded if the mime type of the first one was ok. However, what's the goal to check if the files are instance of `FileUploadedInterface` ? I mean they should always be, no ?

Comment: @Oliv In a perfect world they should be, but you have no control over what a client will send to your backend, they can craft whatever payloads they want. You can mitigate it to some extent using the form protector, but even that cannot protect against every possibly attack vector, so you must always assume that the data that you receive is possibly malicious, and not in the format that you expect. Never take the easy route when it comes to input validation!